# running cshrc script in RHEL 7 from bash account does not work

Tags: bash, shell-script, csh

I was given a software suite which is based around `cshrc`.
Such that a user is supposed to source a `setup.cshrc` file and within that it sources numerous other .cshrc scripts to set up the environment to compile and run a bunch of old fortran written programs.

I am running RHEL 7.9 x86-64, and the author had told me to make a user account, or change my user account, to `/usr/bin/csh` in order to run everything properly.  **Is this really necessary?**

All my attempts to run these csh setup files fail when doing from a bash shell.  However if I do make a local user account in linux where in `/etc/passwd` it says `/usr/bin/csh` instead of `/usr/bin/bash` then all the csh scripts provided to me work when I run them.  But I prefer that all my linux accounts (including mine) is `bash`.  Is there a way to keep my account as `bash` but run these `csh` scripts?

Comment: If you log into your account where `bash` is the default and type `csh` that'll start an instance of the `csh` shell.  If your run the commands at that point, do they work?

Comment: no, they do not work.

Comment: Some mention of what you saw when you tried it might be helpful

Comment: This seems apropos: [**Csh Programming Considered Harmful**](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html)

Answer (score 0):

- You will be able to run your setup file from either `csh` or `tcsh`, generally not from `bash` (it really depends on the content of the `csh` script).
- As a rule for (shell) scripts, if file `setup.cshrc` is properly equipped with a shebang `#!/bin/csh` or `#!/bin/tcsh` (or a variation of that) on its first line, then you need that interpreter to be present because the corresponding shell environment will be called for the content of the script to be properly executed.

If the output of `chsh -l` **includes** `/bin/csh`, or `/bin/tcsh`, just try:

```
$ /bin/csh setup.cshrc         # replace csh by tcsh if needed
```

If the output of `chsh -l` **does NOT include** `/bin/csh`, or `/bin/tcsh`, install `tcsh` on your system:

```
$ sudo yum install tcsh
$ cat /etc/shells       # < check that output includes /bin/tcsh
```

Then you can either run from a shell as above:

```
$ tcsh setup.cshrc
```

or temporarily change your current account's default login shell to `tcsh` with:

```
$ chsh -s tcsh
```

and perform your setup from there.